# json с сервера с html разметкой

Tags: json, swift

Получаю ответ (строку) с сервера (`json`) с `html` разметкой.
Пример:

```
    <p> sometext </p>
```

Как получить чистый текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай расширение для класса `String` Таким образом:

```
extension String {

var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard
        let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

}

и используй этот свойство для нужной тебе строки.

```
var someString =  "<p> sometext </p>"
someString.html2String
```

Удачи.